# Problem with Tableau report trusted ticket URL using JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tableau-api, xss

As the title suggests, there is a problem.

Opening a Tableau‘s report trusted URL using window.open() opens the Tableau site but automatically logs you out. However, if you open the URL using the browser's address bar, it opens normally.

I'll give you more details.

situation:

1. Site A and Tableau Server have different domains. Site A is https and Tableau's trusted ticket URL is http.
2. XSS setup is allowed between these two sites.
3. Chrome allows the ‘Unsafe sites’ setting.
4. The 'Pop-ups and redirects' setting is also allowed.
5. Assuming Tableau's reports trusted ticket URL is a variable called "turl", running window.open(turl, "_blank") in javascript on site A will redirect to the Tableau server, but will also be logged automatically out. However, if you paste turl into the browser's address bar and navigate to the page, the report loads normally.
6. I have tried both opening using the href attribute of the  element and opening using the location.href attribute, but without success.

Please let me know what is causing this problem.